# WebSphere Liberty - JNDI lookup fails

Tags: jndi, websphere-liberty

**I am using Websphere liberty.**
I am getting an problem when i try to access the jndiEntry. The codes below the lookup are not getting executed/
server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <jndiEntry jndiName="schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName" value='"plato"' />

    <iiopEndpoint iiopPort="2809" id="defaultIiopEndpoint">
         <iiopsOptions iiopsPort="2810"></iiopsOptions>
     </iiopEndpoint>
     <orb nameService="corbaname::localhost:2809" iiopEndpointRef="defaultIiopEndpoint">
     </orb>

    <remoteFileAccess>
    <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" />
</server>
```

I am trying to access the jndiEntry from a client code:

```
package com.ibm.test;
import javax.naming.*;

import java.util.*;

public class myTest {

 public static void main( String args[]) {
  try{
      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
      Object object = ctx.lookup("schoolOfAthens/defaultAdminUserName");
      System.out.println("object: ");
  } catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

**When i run the program, the lines below the lookup are not getting executed.**

I am using the following jars:
1. ejbRemotePortable.jar
2. com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_9.0.jar
3. com.ibm.ws.orb_9.0.jar

Comment: Liberty doesn't support remote JNDI lookups other than remote EJB's, which is why this won't work.

Comment: i have problem accessing the remote ejb also

Comment: package com.ibm.test;
import javax.naming.*;

import java.util.*;

public class myTest {

 public static void main( String args[]) {
  try{
   String ejbLookupUrl = "corbaname:rir:#ejb/global/ejbProjectTest/ejbProject/MYEJB!com\\.ibm\\.ejbproject\\.MYEJBRemote";
   InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
   Object obj = ctx.lookup(ejbLookupUrl);
   System.out.println(obj);
   System.out.println("Hello");
  } catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}

Comment: None of the lines below  Object obj = ctx.lookup(ejbLookupUrl) is getting executed